# extracting a pattern from command line argument in shell scipt

Tags: regex, shell

I have to write a shell script which i need to run on many remote servers.
The script basically does traceroute –m   on those servers.

I have to first validate the ip format and then extract the ip address from the input.

Input:-

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1 2222
192.168.1.1:2222
Any garbage values
```

There could be no port in the input, space before port number or a colon.

I have to extract the ip part of the input (`192.168.1.1`)

My script:-

```
 ip=`echo $1`
 re='^([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[ :]([0-9]{1,5})$'
 if [[ $ip =~ $re ]]; then
          ip=`echo $ip | sed 's/[ :].*//'`
          command=$(traceroute -m 9 $ip 2>&1)
          echo "$command"
 else
          echo "Entered ip address is not valid"
 fi
```

how i pass the ip to the script:-

```
$./script.sh 192.168.1.1 2222
```

this script validates the ip but not if i pass ip with spaces and the port number.

input:-192.168.1.1 2222 (not working)

input:- 192.168.1.1:2222 (working)

input:- 192.168.1.1 (not working)
can anyone point out the mistake?

**EDITED**

okay i'm gonna go with this script:-

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 ip="$@"
  3 re='([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})'
  4 if [[ "$ip" =~ $re ]]; then
  5         ip=`echo "$ip" | sed 's/^\([^: ]*\).*$/\1/'`
  6         command=$(traceroute -m 9 "$ip" 2>&1)
  7         echo "$command"
  8 else
  9         echo "Entered ip address is not valid"
 10 fi
```

Anything worth noticing? any scenario which i may have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression needs to remove `^` and `$`.

Have your script like this:

```
re='([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})[ :]'

if [[ "$ip" =~ $re ]]; then
   ip="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
   command=$(traceroute -m 9 "$ip" 2>&1)
   echo "$command"
else
   echo "Entered ip address is not valid"
fi
```

Comment: `ip="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` sometimes does not work on solaris.

can i use `ip=`echo $ip | sed 's/[ :].*//'` instead of that?

Comment: You can try `echo "$ip" | sed 's/^\([^: ]*\).*$/\1/'` if `ip="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

> this script validates the ip but not if i pass ip with spaces.

Because the script's parameters -- `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. -- are split on whitespace.  If you want to treat the entire array as one string, use `$@`.

BTW this:

```
ip=`echo $1`
```

is redundant; `ip=$1` is sufficient (or `ip=$@`).

Your existing regexp will now fail the case of the ip with no port, however.  To correct that, just drop the last part:

```
re='^([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})'
```

If you need to perform a more thorough validation, use `[: ]*[0-9]*$` at the end.